# Nginx pass proxy example.com/test/app

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, 301-redirect

I am trying to configure Nginx as a proxy to http://example.com/test/app

My config is similar to this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location  / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com/test/app;
    }
}
```

I am getting 301 response. I don't think this is something related to the web app the proxy is referring to, because its url is accessible via the browser.

I am quite new to Nginx. Please help. :)

Comment: What do the nginx logs say?

Comment: The Nginx says it's getting an  HTTP response with status code 301 : Moved Permanently.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the proper way to do this is by setting :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location  / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://example.com;
    }
}
```

And then by adding /test/app/ to the address of the Nginx instance.
Eg. http://x.x.x.x/test/app/

Note : It's important to add "/" at the end of the url.